# Remove drop down icon issues

Tags: css, bulma

I've gone through a variety of different solutions for this problem that don't seem to work for me. I'm sure it's because I'm using a CSS framework, Bulma, that tends to take over things a bit for the wrong direction.

I'm trying to remove the drop down icon from a drop-down menu and replace it with an image. I've got the image showing but I can't seem to make the default arrow hide/remove.

```
<div class="control">
 <div id="newAd-Preview" class="select">
  <select>
   <option >
    test
   </option>
   <option>Key</option>
   <option>Hello</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle with some solutions that I've found but don't seem to work. It also already has bulma linked. https://jsfiddle.net/uxgdp3b9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this definition:

```
.select:not(.is-multiple):not(.is-loading)::after {
    background: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.4.8/collection/icon/svg/ios-arrow-dropdown.svg") no-repeat;
    transform: rotate(0);
    border: none;  
    width: 20px;  
    background-position: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
.select {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;

}

select::-ms-expand
{
        display: none;
}

.select:not(.is-multiple) {
  height: 2.25em;
}

.select:not(.is-multiple):not(.is-loading)::after {
  background: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.4.8/collection/icon/svg/ios-arrow-dropdown.svg") no-repeat !important;
  transform: rotate(0) !important;
  border: none !important;  
  width: 20px !important;  
  background-position: 50% !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  right: 5px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="control">
  <div id="newAd-Preview" class="select">
    <select>
      <option >
        test
      </option>
      <option>Key</option>
      <option>Hello</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I needed to add the `!important` flags because SO's snippet doesn't include the CSS file in the header. If your Bulma CSS file is overridden by your CSS file, you don't need the `!important` flags.